# JSP cannot detect new added element in java model class

Tags: java, jsp

Here is my java model class - CustomerProperty.java

```
package model;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class CustomerProperty {

public CustomerProperty() {

}

public int propertyid;
public String name;
public String phone;
public String occupation;
public String address1;
public String address2;
public String postcode;
public String city;
public String state;
public String payment;
public InputStream photo;
public String agent;
public String IDproject;
public String[] quickSale;
public String ICnumber;
public String bag;
public String mydate;

public int getPropertyid() {
    return propertyid;
}

public void setPropertyid(int propertyid) {
    this.propertyid = propertyid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getICnumber() {
    return ICnumber;
}

public void setICnumber(String ICnumber) {
    this.ICnumber = ICnumber;
}

public String getICNUMBER() {
    return ICnumber;
}

public void setICNUMBER(String ICnumber) {
    this.ICnumber = ICnumber;
}

public String getOccupation() {
    return occupation;
}

public void setOccupation(String occupation) {
    this.occupation = occupation;
}

public String getAddress1() {
    return address1;
}

public void setAddress1(String address1) {
    this.address1 = address1;
}

public String getAddress2() {
    return address2;
}

public void setAddress2(String address2) {
    this.address2 = address2;
}

public String getPostcode() {
    return postcode;
}

public void setPostcode(String postcode) {
    this.postcode = postcode;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String dateTime) {
    this.state = dateTime;
}

public String getPayment() {
    return payment;
}

public void setPayment(String payment) {
    this.payment = payment;
}

public InputStream getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}

public void setPhoto(InputStream photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}

public String getAgent() {
    return agent;
}

public void setAgent(String agent) {
    this.agent = agent;
}

public String getIDproject() {
    return IDproject;
}

public void setIDproject(String IDproject) {
    this.IDproject = IDproject;
}

public String[] getQuickSale() {
    return quickSale;
}

public void setQuickSale(String[] quickSale) {
    this.quickSale = quickSale;
}

public String getMyDate() {
    return mydate;
}

public void setMyDate(String mydate) {
    this.mydate = mydate;
}
```

Whenever my JSP calling this java class, it only can detect the original element. I have added a new element - mydate and it is like forever cannot detect it.

Below is the error code.

> pe Exception report
>
> messageInternal Server Error
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:
>   The class 'model.CustomerProperty' does not have the property
>   'mydate'. root cause
>
> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'model.CustomerProperty'
>   does not have the property 'mydate'. note The full stack traces of the
>   exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server
>   Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.

I have try to delete the java class and recreate again but still, the JSP only can detect for my first 16 elements and not any new added element.

Any solutions? Thanks

Below is my JSP file code.

```
<head>
    <title>Project Sales Report</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
</head>
<body>

    <p align="center" style="font-family:times;font-size:40pt"><c:out value="${project2.projectName}"/> Sales Report</p>
    <table align="center" bgcolor="silver" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" class="customer" >
        <thead>
            <tr>             
                <th>Unit ID</th>
                <th>Agent</th>
                <th>Customer Name</th>
                <th>IC Number</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
                <th>Occupation</th>
                <th>Address 1</th>
                <th>Address 2</th>
                <th>Postcode</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Payment Type</th>
                <th>Receipt</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${customerdetail}" var="abc">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${abc.propertyid}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${abc.agent}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${abc.name}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${abc.ICnumber}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${abc.phone}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${abc.occupation}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${abc.address1}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${abc.address2}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${abc.postcode}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${abc.city}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${abc.mydate}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${abc.payment}" /></td>
                </tr> 
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div align="center">
        <button type="button" style="width:70px;">Print</button>
        <input type="button" value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);
                return true;" style="width:70px;"/>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your project

Comment: Your getter and setter on this field are wrong.
Please use setMyDate() and getMyDate()

Comment: I try to edit the name accordingly but still, propertyNotFound

Comment: Is it the same propertyNotFound? it looks like getBag() and setBag() are also implemented wrongly, as well as extra getters/setters for ICnumber: getICNUMBER() amd setICNUMBER.

Comment: Ya, same propertyNotFound - mydate. Im using Netbean 8.0.

Comment: r u using spring?? how do you pass value to this page??  any servlet? or controller??

Comment: incorrect capitalization suggestion was used by drgPP for your property: it should be getMydate() and setMydate(), since mydate is the property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note your getter setters -

```
public String mybag() {
    return mydate;
}

public void setmybag(String mydate) {
    this.mydate = mydate;
}
```

It should be `setMydate` and `getMydate`. isn't it ?

**Update -**

It is case sensative.

```
public String mydate;
```

this should be

```
public String myDate;
```

Your JSP should be `abc.myDate` and not `abc.mydate`

```
<td><c:out value="${abc.mydate}" /></td>
```

Comment: I already edit to setMyDate(String mydate) and getMyDate accordingly. But still property not found

Comment: Change case in JSP..it should be `abc.myDate` and not `abc.mydate`..as per your getter-sertters.

Comment: Thanks, My problem solved.
Anyway, my java model class is 

public String mydate;

Why I need to use abc.myDate instead of mydate?

Comment: Because in getter -setter method you are using Upper case.

Comment: Thanks bro,
You save my day. 
Thanks Thanks :)
Your 10 minutes guide > my 4 years' lecturer in university.